# Infinite Loop for sequelize-query with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, async-await, sequelize.js

I want to call a function, that includes a sequelize query (returns an order) in an infinite loop, meaning to recall the function again when it is resolved, so searching always for a new order.

My original approach was

```
do {
    (async function () {
        var nextOrder = await getNextOrder()
        console.log("nextOrder",nextOrder)
    })(); 
} while (ENV == "development");
```

that is calling:

```
function getNextOrder() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            Orders.findOne({
                where: {
                    type: {
                        [Op.or]: ["buy", "sell"]
                    },
                },
            }).then(async nextOrder => {
                // Doing stuff with next order
                return resolve()
            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log("error", e)
                return reject(e)
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error", e)
            return reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```

The problem with above approach is, that the function: getNextOrder never resolves and the while-loop just calls it permanently. What needs to be done to get above code working by calling the same function again and again, but after it resolved?

Now I ended up with the following approach, which is working, but it would be interesting to get the async/await approach above working.

```
getNextOrder()
```

that is calling:

```
function getNextOrder() {
    Orders.findOne({
        where: {
            type: {
                [Op.or]: ["buy", "sell"]
            },
        },
    }).then(async nextOrder => {
        // Doing stuff with next order
    }).then(function() {
        getNextOrder() // <------ Calling function again here
        return
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e)
        return
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `async` in the `new Promise(async (resolve, reject)` piece of the code OR use `async/await` inside the function:

```
function getNextOrder() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const nextOrder = await Orders.findOne({
                where: {
                    type: {
                        [Op.or]: ["buy", "sell"]
                    },
                },
            })
            // Doing stuff with next order
            return resolve()
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error", e)
            return reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```